# Binding multiple handlers to elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

Hey, I'm new to JavaScript so this is most probably going to sound really basic but here goes.

My web page is made up of "modules" which I load into the page with jQuery, so that my JavaScript works with the new content that has been loaded into the page, I have been told to use callback functions.

My problem is though, how do I activate multiple callback functions?

here is some of my code:

```
function loadLoginForm() {
$('[name=loadLoginForm]').click(function() {
$("#mainWrap").css({ width:"300px", height:"200px" });
$("#mainWrap").load("modules/web/loginForm.php", null, loadRegisterForm);
});
}
```

This bit of code activates the function named "loadRegisterForm" but what do i do if I want to activate more than one?

I've tried a few ways of how I think it would be done but to no avail, also I tried Google but I believe I'm using the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be something like what you need?:

```
function loadLoginForm() {
$('[name=loadLoginForm]').click(function() {
$("#mainWrap").css({ width:"300px", height:"200px" });
$("#mainWrap").load("modules/web/loginForm.php", null, function(data) {
  loadRegisterForm_1(data);
  loadRegisterForm_2(data);
  loadRegisterForm_3(data);
});
});
}
```

EDIT II:

```
function loadLoginForm() {
$('[name=loadLoginForm]').click(function() {
$("#mainWrap").css({ width:"300px", height:"200px" });
$("#mainWrap").load("modules/web/loginForm.php", null, function(data) {
  loadRegisterForm_1.call(this, data);
  loadRegisterForm_2.call(this, data);
  loadRegisterForm_3.call(this, data);
});
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works a treat. The first code you gave works fine what does the edited version do different?

Comment: send the context, I think it does not interest you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Function:call